# Maximal ideals of polynomial ring $R[x]$ over a commutative ring $R$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals, irreducible-polynomials

In the article [1](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002186939090210F), Page 46, the author notes that:

> At this point it should be noted that there is an obvious connection with
>   commutative rings. In fact, if $R$ is a commutative domain and $T= C$ is the
>   field of fractions of $R$, the results obtained in Section $2$ concerning prime ideals are well known.

For a commutative ring $R$, what are the prime (maximal) ideals of the polynomial ring $R[x]$? Can they be characterized by their generators?

Comment: The link article 1 doesn't work

Comment: If $R$ is a field, then yes: the generators must be irreducible. But unless $R$ is Noetherian, it is not even clear if prime ideals are finitely generated, let alone how you would characterize them.

Comment: So sorry. The link is corrected. Try it now.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you know the prime ideals of a commutative ring $R$ very well, there is nothing substantial you can say about the prime ideals of $R[x]$: if there were algebraic geometers  would be out of business!
For example it is very easy to determine the prime ideals of $R=\mathbb C[y,z]$ but essentially impossible to classify the height-$2$ prime ideals of $R[x]$, which correspond to curves in $\mathbb A^3_\mathbb C$
Even calculating the minimal number of generators (which can be arbitrarily large, as shown by Macaulay) for such an ideal is a daunting task.

As to the article you refer to:  the author is interested only in the very special case where $R$ is a "prime ring", a concept he does not define and which probably means  a ring without strict subring. 
This an extremely restricted class of rings, to say the least.