# Maximal ideal in R[X] where R is a commutative ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Suppose $R$ is any commutative ring which is not a field. I am trying to show that maximal ideals of $R[X]$ should be of the form $\left<m,f(x)\right>$, where $m$ is a maximal ideal in $R$ and $f(x)$ is irreducible mod $m$.

While this particular result seems to be true when $R$ is any noetherian ring of dimension at most $1$, can someone prove in general if the result is true? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457852/maximal-ideals-of-polynomial-ring-rx-over-a-commutative-ring-r).

Comment: Ohh thanks I am also thinking for height 2 rings this result may not be true

Comment: There is a case that you missed : $R=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}$ (the rationals with $p$ not dividing the denominator) then $\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}[X]/(pX-1)=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}[p^{-1}]=\Bbb{Q}$ so $(pX-1)$ is a maximal ideal

Comment: @reuns I think any element of the form $ax-b$, where $a,b \in Z_p$, with $a,b \neq 0$ belong to the quotient set

Comment: @user631697 I don't see what you mean, $\Bbb{Q}=\Bbb{Z}_{(p)}[p^{-1}]\cong \Bbb{Z}_{(p)}[X]/(pX-1)$.  user26857's example is the same with another local ring : $K[[T]]$ whose fraction field is $K[[T]][T^{-1}]$